# Drop down menu conflict

Tags: html, css, function, drop-down-menu, carousel

I'm a student in the process of coding a website for a school project. My level is very beginner (coding is extremely difficult for me) so my apologies if my question is very amateur. I'm creating a site that will display a collection of postcards. I'm trying to get my dropdown menu to work, however on some pages it seems to function, while other pages it doesn't (mainly the pages that have a carousel on them). I will post my code (HTML + CSS below) but my layout is a body container, then top and bottom containers. The carousel (in the bottom container) is where photos of my postcard collection would go, while the drop down menu is in the top container. The dropdown menu isn't functioning properly and the styling isn't totally on point (the "MENU" text will not display in the typeface I need). The carousel works perfectly fine though on the same page.

```
  HTML

    <!--Developed by Matthew Nielsen-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Carousel Collection</title>

<html>

<head>

  <meta name="Mattew Nielsen" content="Collection Interface">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/carouselStyle.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans|Neuton|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="bodyContainer">


    <div class="topcontainer">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="/pages/continents.html">Continents</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottomContainer">
        <div class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="/images/AS1.jpg">
            </div>
            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="/images/AS2.jpg">
            </div>
            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="/images/AS3.jpg">
            </div>
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li>
                <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


CSS

/* carouselStyle.css */

/*Developed by Matthew Nielsen*/

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bodyContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/images/message.JPG);
  opacity: .5;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Top Container + Nav Bar */

.topContainer {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Bottom Container + Carousel */

.bottomContainer {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  align-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  align-content: center;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #428bca;
}

/*
#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
} */
```

I am curious if anyone that views this might see any glaring problems or have recommendations on how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: For one thing  in .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white; // COLOR IS WHITE AND SO IS THE BACKGROUND
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

Comment: I think this exemple can help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

Answer (score 0):

Your drop-down nav is actually working great! If you comment out `.bottomcontainer` you can see that it works properly upon hovering, and all links seem to be clickable.

The trouble is with your positioning of the carousel:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative; /* remove this */
  align-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  margin-top: 26px;
}
```

Right now, with `position: relative;` your carousel is covering the site. You can't technically hover over the nav behind it, even though you can see it. It's unnecessary to use `relative` in the snippet you've provided. Remove that line of code and you'll find that formatting doesn't change, the nav bar works properly, and your carousel still works.

Some further information on `position: ;` can be found at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

A further suggestion from my own design guidelines, I recommend that you separate the divs for a top and bottom container like this:

```
<div class="bodyContainer">
  <div class="topcontainer">
    /* nav stuff */
  </div>
  <div class="bottomContainer">
    /* carousel stuff */
  </div>
</div>
```

It will clean up the inherited style the bottom container might accidentally steal from your nav bar and less involved elements will help you troubleshoot those style troubles you were having. It will also help you to visualize your site with two separate elements working alongside each other.

Finally, you'll want to close all style traits with a semi-colon (;) in places like this. I noticed a few of these throughout your code. It is compiling fine, but it will cause confusion when you try to add another line.

```
.topContainer {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%     /* <--- here */
}
```